# Find unique records from list based on latest timestamp in java

Tags: java

I have a list contains list of object with duplicates and only differs on timestamp and I need to get latest timestamp value.

I am adding some mock data similar to my case

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add( new Person( name1,created, 1563428880 ));
personList.add( new Person( name2,created, 1563428880 ));
personList.add( new Person( name3,created, 1563428880 ));
personList.add( new Person( name2,updated, 1563429998 ));
personList.add( new Person( name3,updated, 1563429998 ));
```

I have below code to get the unique object from the list

```
for (Person person: personList) {
    if(uniqueLatestPersonMap.containsKey( person.getName() )) {
        Person availablePerson = uniqueLatestPersonMap.get(person.getName());
        int status = availablePerson.getTimestamp().compareTo(person.getTimestamp());
        if(status  == -1) {
            uniqueLatestPersonMap.put(person.getName(),person); 
        }
    } else {
        uniqueLatestPersonMap.put(person.getName(),person);
    }
}
```

Because of my large data and response time not as we are expected. Is there any way we can improve the response time or any alter way to do it efficiently.

My output list will have the

```
Person( name1,created, 1563428880 )
Person( name2,updated, 1563429998 );
Person( name3,updated, 1563429998 );
```

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: You iterate once, meaning O(n) and check in a map which is generally O(1), which is as good as it gets. What `Map` implementation do you use, how large is your data, what is the time it takes, how quick *should* it be?

Comment: 20 million records and takes more time to process the data between 10 min to 20 minutes also we are looking for any way to improve the code @luk2302

Comment: I think it is a **VERY** bad idea to have 20M records (including Strings) in memory. Where does the data come from?

Comment: That is the max amount of data we have ported to validate the performance and QA team dumped the data  We are expecting half a million records the most but performance team trying out @luk2302

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the arraylist by name then process the data and check the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's TreeMap for uniqueLatestPersonMap. This will limit the number of comparisons when searching uniqueLatestPersonMap.containsKey( person.getName()) for existing names.

Answer (score 0):

Please override `equals` and `hashCode` using your unique attribute; `timeStamp` in your case.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Person person = (Person) o;
    return getTimeStamp() == person.getTimeStamp();
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getTimeStamp());
}
```

and following `Java8` code will get unique records from list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
    personList.add(new Person("person1", 1563428880));
    personList.add(new Person("person2", 1563428881));
    personList.add(new Person("person3", 1563428883));
    personList.add(new Person("person4", 1563428880));

    Collection<Person> uniquePersonList = getUniquePersonList(personList);
    uniquePersonList.forEach(System.out::println);

}
private static Collection<Person> getUniquePersonList(List<Person> personList) {
    return personList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getTimeStamp, Function.identity(), (person1, person2) -> person1))
            .values();
}
```

Hence the output will be following.

```
Person{name='person1', timeStamp=1563428880}
Person{name='person2', timeStamp=1563428881}
Person{name='person3', timeStamp=1563428883}
```

Note: some obvious code (getter, setter, attributes and `toString()`) is omitted for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Stream API.

I tried with 5M and it tooks around 10s. (I only have 3 different names, so I think that it helps the performances.)

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String []args){
    List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5_000_000; i++) {
        personList.add(new Person("name1", 1563428880 +i));
        personList.add(new Person("name2", 1563428880+i));
        personList.add(new Person("name3", 1563428880+i));
        personList.add(new Person("name2", 1563429998+i));
        personList.add(new Person("name3", 1563429998+i));
    }

    System.out.println("starting ..");
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Groups persons by name
    Map<String, List<Person>> m = personList.parallelStream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName));

    // For each name, get the person with the highest timestamp
    List<Person> p = m.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> e.getValue().parallelStream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getTime)))
            .filter(Optional::isPresent)
            .map(Optional::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("done in " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + "ms.");
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

> ```
> starting ..
> done in 8874ms.
> [name3-1568429997, name2-1568429997, name1-1568428879]
> ```